# Combining multiple geo sources in Tableau

Tags: maps, gis, geospatial, tableau-api

I want to create a filled map of administrative regions (districts, counties etc.) for a particular country where the intensity of color depends on some measure of these closed areas.

I have 2 data sources.

1. This contains the lat-long values and name of the area. This table contains all the points required to define a closed polygon for an administrative area.
2. Here I have a numeric value and lat-long positions of where this value was recorded.

Using tableau and the first data source, I could create a filled map of the administrative regions and assign arbitrary colors to them.

I want to use the second data source and use some aggregate, say AVG, on my numeric value that was recorded at lat-long values that fall in one of the polygons computed earlier and use them to color the polygons.

Is there some way to do this?

(I have not used Tableau in the past. But, I loved the way it can handle some basic plotting tasks. I have a feeling that it should be possible with Tableau, but could not find any tutorial on how to get this.)

Comment: This may require a certain amount of pre-processing on the data. Tableau doesn't have geo-query ability (to tell whether a point is inside a polygon). But a simple additional column specifying the point-to-polygon link (mapping software or python geography library's would make this easy to generate) would make your goal easy in Tableau.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up preparing the data using Python before sending it to Tableau.